# WireMock always unexpectedly return 404

Tags: spring-boot-test, wiremock

I am using openjdk 17.0.5 and SpringBoot 2.7.5 and trying to set up WireMock (2.35.0) for a simple test, but the actual response is always return 404. So I have create a WireMockBase class like this:

```
public class WireMockBase {
  
  protected static WireMockServer wireMockServer;
  
  public static WireMockServer startWireMockServer() {
    wireMockServer = new WireMockServer(options().port("6677"));
    wireMockServer.start();
    return wireMockServer;
  }
  
  @PreDestroy
  public static void stopWireMockServer() {
    wireMockServer.stop();
  }
}
```

Then I create a simple test class:

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class SimpleTest extends WireMockBase {
 @BeforeEach
  public void setup(){
    startWireMockServer();
  }
@Test
  void testGetRequest() throws Exception {
 wireMockServer.stubFor(get(urlEqualTo("/some/thing"))
        .willReturn(aResponse()
            .withHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain")
            .withBody("Hello world!")));
  
    assertEquals("Hello world!", restTemplate.getForEntity("/some/thing", String.class).getBody());
}
   }
```

However, the result I got is

```
Expected :{"timestamp":"2023-02-04T05:07:46.320+00:00","status":404,"error":"Not Found","path":"/some/thing"}
Actual   :Hello world!
```

Does any know why I got an unexpected result with status:404 instead of Hello World?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the issue is that the `RestTemplate` instance has its base URL set to the Spring Boot app, not the WireMock server, so the 404 you're getting  is from your app under test rather than WireMock.

If you'd like to try explicitly testing the WireMock stub directly (not hitting the Spring app) try passing the absolute URL:

```java
restTemplate.getForEntity("http://localhost:6677/some/thing", String.class).getBody()
```

Comment: Yeah. Thanks a lot. I added the host and eventually, it worked!